# Selecting a list item on a touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ipad, touchscreen

I've found multiple threads based on or around this question however the answers so far **haven't helped what so ever**. I'm trying to get this to work through pure JavaScript (JQuery accepted).

So far I have it working so that I can select an item via web browser on a computer but the click event doesn't seem to work with touch screens. I've tried multiple "solutions" from other threads such as adding touch for example:

```
$('.List').on('click touch', function () {
// code
});
```

My current JavaScript (Works on pc):

```
document.querySelector('.List').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var selected;

if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    selected = document.querySelector('li.selected');
    if (selected)
        selected.classList = '';
    e.target.classList = 'selected'
}

document.getElementById('ItemValue').value = e.target.innerText;
```

});

In the above JavaScript I'm simply adding a colour to the background of the list item and getting the inner text and storing it.

My list (Items are added at runtime)

```
<div id="SelectedItems" class="ListBox">
  <ul id="Selected" class="List ItemList" runat="server" >
    <%--List items here--%>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included Jquery library before using Jquery?

Comment: Ahh... I'll try that now.. this page is the only page that doesn't use the master page that has the reference in it.

Comment: I guess we all have our blonde moment every so often, wow I can't believe I missed that. It works now thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sure, you are including the Jquery library, try using this solution.

Since all your list items are loading at run time, you can also use like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#Selected li' function () {
          // code
    });
});
```

Comment: The code from another thread that was included in the examples in the question works now that I've included the library. Thanks again for pointing that out :)

Comment: My pleasure :).